# Clear Woocommerce cart when sending multiple items by url

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need the Woocommerce cart to be cleaned in case I send more than four items to it via url.

I came up with this code, but it only cleans the cart if there are already five items in it.

```
//in functions.php

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'remove_cart_item_before_add_to_cart', 20, 3 );
function remove_cart_item_before_add_to_cart( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ) {
    if( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() >= 5  )
        WC()->cart->empty_cart();
    return $passed;
}
```

Another problem is that, even the code above that is not useful to me, does not work if I add multiple courses via url, as in:

```
https://exemple.net/cart?fill_cart=100,101,102,103,104,105,106
```

That is, the code in `functions.php` only works from the website, and not by url.

All I need is clear the cart when sending more than 4 items **by url**.

I prefer a solution in PHP, but a JS solution will do. Thanks for who can help me.

Comment: Did you try changing the 5 to a 4?

Comment: @HowardE the question is not about if the conditional statement is correct. But thanks for the intent to help.

Comment: What does this do? https://exemple.net/cart?fill_cart=100,101,102,103,104,105,106 can you post the function that is getting that URL param? Or is that what you want to get here... A function to do that?

Comment: @HowardE the "fill_cart" parameter comes with the Cart Links plugin for WooCommerce. I need clear the cart when sending more than 4 items by url, 
whether using fill_cart or not, but by url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using the free plugin [Cart links for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/soft79-cart-links-for-woocommerce/), and making a few change in its code.

I will describe below what I did:

1) To start install the plugin, this will allow you to add products using the `fill_cart` parameter in url (as described in my question)

2) edit the plugin file `soft79-cart-links-for-woocommerce.php` found at: `yoursite/wp-content/plugins/soft79-cart-links-for-woocommerce/`

3) go to line 141 or find the declaration of the method `fill_cart`

Inside the `fill_cart` method uncomment (or add) the code to clean the cart:

```
public function fill_cart( $fill_string ) {

    $original_notices = wc_get_notices();
    wc_clear_notices();

    ////Clear the cart
    //WC()->cart->empty_cart(); <-- uncomment here!
```

Save the file. Now any new items that arrive via url must clean the cart first.

Comment: Note: this solution is a little different from my question, as the company's sales department informed me that I no longer need to check if there are more than four items on the link, just clean the cart before a new item arrives via url. Thanks @HowardE! Our conversation gave me other ideas!